# Specific Excel Search Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am struggling with this one for a week now:
Example:
Column A is list of IP addresses, Column B is a list of red flag or bad ips.
Does someone knows the formula so i can count how many Bad ips are in list that is in Column A?
Here is a Screenshot:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2wvj.png

Or Url https://prnt.sc/sFIMx7iD2HOf

I need help with code that will show me how many times B3 is in list A3:A20?

I appreciate the help!
Thank you All

Comment: So, answer will be `0` as there is no `63.155` in column A, as per your given screenshot?

Comment: Can you please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text? [See here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why. See [/editing-help#code](/editing-help#code) for how to format code blocks. See also: [/editing-help#tables](/editing-help#tables).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IP's are nothing but texts in Excel. So, you can use `COUNTIFS()` with wildcard `*`. Try below formula for partial matching.

```
=COUNTIFS($A$3:$A$20,"*"&B3&"*")
```

[image]